# Automatic create folders in directory c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, directory

I need a script that can create a sub folders automaticaly.

For example:

I have a base folder stored at `c:/upload`. I tranfer to script folders string: `/2011/23/12/3`. Script should parse this string and create folders and subfolders in `c:/upload` like string is (should be `c:/upload/2011/23/12/3`)

How can I make this?

Now I use if/else and check if folder/subfolder exist, but the script is tooooo big and that is hard to manage.

Comment: What is the last folder? I'm referring to the number three. Seems like you basically use c:\upload\yyyy\MM\dd

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you looked at [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx), which will create any missing directories along the way?

From the documentation:

> Any and all directories specified in path are created, unless they already exist or unless some part of path is invalid.

Comment: all directories in the path that not exist yet will be created? for example Directory.CreateDirectory("c:/upload/2011/23/12/3") where 23,12,3 not exist will be created using this function?

Comment: @evgeniy.labusnkiy As easy as test it :)

Comment: @evgeniy: Yes. Read the documentation I linked to: "Any and all directories specified in path are created, unless they already exist or unless some part of path is invalid. "

Comment: realy, i dont know that this is so simple :)))

Answer (score 6):

Your code to create directories recursively will be as simple as:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
```

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin: I didnt notice the asp.net-mvc tag earlier. However, the method call to do this remains the same.

Comment: indeed it does. That's basically what @Jon wrote as well. I only objected to creating a console app

Comment: Please, at least test your code before posting it. Where is the overload that receives a `bool`?

Comment: Darn it. Two in a row :(. That's what happens when you answer a question which @Jon Skeet has already answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Directory.CreateDirectory` in C# for creating directory.